# Creating directory in application package on internal storage

Tags: android

Is it possible for android application to create several directories in internal storage for storing there different kinds of files? I need this capability, because I'll need to delete a kind of files at definite time moment in my application.

When I try to use standard `Context` method `openFileOutput()` and send to it filename with "/" symbol I get `IllegalArgumentException`.

Tell me please what classes and methods could allow me such functionality?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124612/android-create-folders-in-internal-memory/9707270#9707270

Comment: I had a similar problem. And resolved it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124612/android-create-folders-in-internal-memory/9707270#9707270

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use [Context.getDir(String name, int mode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method to create or access directories in internal storage. Quote from docs:

> Retrieve, creating if needed, a new directory in which the application can place its own custom data files. You can use the returned File object to create and access files in this directory. Note that files created through a File object will only be accessible by your own application; you can only set the mode of the entire directory, not of individual files.

UPD Example:

```
File mydir = context.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myfile"); //Getting a file within the dir.
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir); //Use the stream as usual to write into the file.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responding. Could you explain me please. When I create the `File` object using `Context.getDir()`, how could I add to this `File` object another `File` object?