# Android create folders in Internal Memory

Tags: android, storage, internal

Is there any way/ is it allowed to create folders in Internal Memory in Android. Example :

```
- data
-- com.test.app (application's main package)
---databases (database files)
---files (private files for application)
---shared_prefs (shared preferences)

---users (folder which I want to create)
```

Can I create `users` folder in Internal Memory for example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating directory in application package on internal storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105919/creating-directory-in-application-package-on-internal-storage)

Comment: Yeah you can definitely make folder inside memory

Comment: For Android 12, https://stackoverflow.com/a/73611338/2126077

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I used this to create folder/file in internal memory :

```
File mydir = context.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myfile"); //Getting a file within the dir.
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir); //Use the stream as usual to write into the file.
```

Comment: Seems a helpful answer from the upvotes.. Can you please mention the code for reading the contents of same file, line by line..Since now the file is inside the "mydir" directory, how to do the reading of it..And what if there are further folders in the directory? The "path" is what i am concerned about.

Comment: @Gautam M. Check if this tutorial works for you. Thanks. http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/android-internal-external-storage.html

Comment: FYI on my Huawei the private files/folders are stored here: /data/user/0/your.app.name. It is also the only folder that the app itself can access. Some phones are not so restrictive and let you access even the root directory.

Answer (score 22):

YOU SHOULD NOT USE THIS IF YOU WANT YOUR FILES TO BE ACCESSED BY USER EASILY

```
File newdir= context.getDir("DirName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  //Don't do
if (!newdir.exists())
    newdir.mkdirs();
```

INSTEAD, do this:

To create directory on phone primary storage memory (generally internal memory) you should use following code. Please note that ExternalStorage in *Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()* does not necessarily refers to sdcard, it returns phone primary storage memory

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyDirName");

if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
    if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
        Log.d("App", "failed to create directory");
    }
}
```

Directory created using this code will be visible to phone user easily. The other method (mentioned first) creates directory in location (/data/data/package.name/app_MyDirName), hence normal phone user will not be able to access it easily and so you should not use it to store video/photo etc.

You will need permissions, in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: yes, you are right, getExternalStorageDirectory() refers to the phone's primary storage,how do you create a folder in sd card then??

Comment: This code is not creating a separate folder like whatsapp..

Comment: @prodev getExternalStorageDirectory() is not creating folder under internal storage just creating in sdcard for real device... We tested your answer and not worked...

Comment: For me it's working fine in Emulator, But when I tried to run same application using usb cable in physical, It shows _Error:: failed to create directory_. I have also allowed storage access.@prodev

Answer (score 4):

context.getDir("mydir", ...); This creates your.package/app_mydir/

```
 /** Retrieve or creates <b>path</b>structure inside in your /data/data/you.app.package/
 * @param path "dir1/dir2/dir3"
 * @return
 */
private File getChildrenFolder(String path) {
            File dir = context.getFilesDir();
    List<String> dirs = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.<String>asList(path.split("/")));
    for(int i = 0; i < dirs.size(); ++i) {
        dir = new File(dir, dirs.get(i)); //Getting a file within the dir.
        if(!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir();
        }
    }
    return dir;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Android change his security about Storage,
For more details check the video [Storage access with Android 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjyYCUW-9tY&ab_channel=AndroidDevelopers)

Also you can try this in android 10

```
File mydir = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir("Directory Name").getAbsolutePath());
    if (!mydir.exists())
    {
        mydir.mkdirs();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Directory Created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

The path of your directory will be in your app data.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private File createFile(String fName)  {
            String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/" + fName+".wav";
            File newFile = new File(filePath);
            println(":File path = "+newFile+"\n "+filePath);
            if (!newFile.exists()) {
                try {
                    newFile.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    toastMsg("Unable to Create New File !");
                }
            } else {
                toastMsg("File Already Exists");

            }

            return newFile;

        }
```

//Request Multiple Permissions

```
private void reqMulPerm(){
        String permissions[]={
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        };

        if(permissions.length!=0){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions,1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "FolderName");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            try {
               Files.createDirectory(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            f.mkdir();
            f.mkdirs();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), f.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: A little explanation on why this approach works would go a long way. ;-)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/66731050/13082664] explain in detail

Comment: I mean you should add some explanation to guide people who might stumble on this answer in the future. Code-only answers are low quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
//gets path of the directory("imRec") in Android's data folder
File file=new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir("imRec").getAbsolutePath());

if (!file.exists()) {  //if directory by that name doesn't exist
    if (!file.mkdirs()) { //we create the directory
          //if still directory doesn't get created ERROR mssg gets displayed
          //which in most cases won't happen
          Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).