# How to create folder in internal memory

Tags: android

This is my application memory path `/data/data/com.myexample.folder/files`  and it works fine but when I create a new directory like this  `/data/data/com.myexample.folder/files/photos`,
it is not created and I wonder what's wrong? How do I create a new folder inside application.

```
public void loadFeed();
String file paths="data/data/com.myapplication.myfolder/files";
File outputFiles= new file(filePaths);
File files1=outputFile1.listFiles();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8124723/931982

Comment: Have you given the permission in manifest?

Comment: check it [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130932/how-to-create-directory-automatically-on-sd-card)

Comment: this path is work fine String file paths="data/data/com.myapplication.myfolder/files"  but when i add new sub directory like this String file paths="data/data/com.myapplication.myfolder/files/photos"  is not display anything

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android create folders in Internal Memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124612/android-create-folders-in-internal-memory)

Answer (score 1):

For your own directory in file storage:

```
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/camtest");
dir.mkdirs();
String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

For saving in sub directory inandroid public folders say DCIM:

use File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

Mainly, make sure that your app has the storage permission enabled:

Go to Device Settings>Device>Applications>Application Manager>"your app">Permissions>Enable Storage permission!

Answer (score 0):

Call [openFileOutput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with the name of the file and the operating mode.

```
    String FILENAME = "hello_file";
    String string = "hello world!";

    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(string.getBytes());
    fos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this way:

```
public void createFile(Context c) throws IOException{
     String FILENAME = timeStamp();
     String string = "hello world!";

     FileOutputStream fos = c.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(string.getBytes());
    fos.close();


}
```