# How in eclipse create folder in internal storage

Tags: android

How can I create folders in Eclipse in internal storage? In this folder I would put a few images. I don't want to create folder via code like [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124612/android-create-folders-in-internal-memory)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Open the DDMS perspective.
- Select your emulator.
- Make the folder by clicking on the green **+** icon.

Comment: Typically, under `/mnt/sdcard`