# Folder creation internal Memory

Tags: android

How can I Create a folder in the internal memory of android device not on SD card with code?Do I need any permission to be set in Manifest ?
I want to create a text file in that directory and save data to that text file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android create folders in Internal Memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124612/android-create-folders-in-internal-memory)

Answer (score 0):

See what the Google docs says here:

> You don’t need any permissions to save files on the internal storage. Your application always has permission to read and write files in its internal storage directory.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: Can You give Android code to create a Folder in the internal memory coz am new and With File???

Comment: i hope this will help you   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124612/android-create-folders-in-internal-memory