# How to create folder in external storage android? I have tried all the other answers on stackoverflow but none is working for me.

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code to create a folder.

```
File mydir= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"My Folder");
    if (!mydir.exists()) {
        mydir.mkdirs();

    }
```

I have also added permissions to write to external storage but I am not finding any folder in my phone storage. I am using LG G2 which has internal memory and does not support sdcard.

Comment: Please refer to this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8124723/4056108)

Comment: heve you checked, which path you get in `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"My Folder"`?

Comment: Use the return value of mkdirs() and display different Toasts() for true/false.

Comment: Which Android version? For 6 and above you need to add code to ask the user to grant those permissions. Google runtime permission.

Comment: Thanks @greenapps I had to manually turn on permission from the settings because my phone is running android 6.0.