# Directory not creating in internal storage

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to create a directory in the internal storage into an Android device using the following code but it seems like I am missing something. The directory is not showing in the internal storage. I have tried this code:

```
File testDir = DirectoryTestActivity.this.getDir("Test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      if (!testDir.exists())
      {
        testDir.mkdirs();
      }
```

Comment: you mean to say in app preference?? because you added this Context.MODE_PRIVATE

Comment: Please ensure that the question you asked is not exist in stack overflowPossible duplicate of [Android create folders in Internal Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124612/android-create-folders-in-internal-memory)

Answer (score 1):

> add you internal path in new File(your internal path )

```
    File newFolderVideos = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures");
   if (!newFolderVideos .exists()) {
    newFolderVideos.mkdirs();
    }
```