# Can't create new directory on internal storage

Tags: java, android, android-file, android-storage

I am trying to write a new folder in internal storage, however it's not created no matter what I do.

Here is the code I use:

```
        File file = new File(path,"TestFolder");
        file.mkdirs();
        Log.e("file path","" + file);
```

The file output is `/storage/emulated/0/TestFolder` which is the exact path I want to write the storage to, but it's not writing.

I added these permission in the manifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I also added this line `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the `<application>` tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android create folders in Internal Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124612/android-create-folders-in-internal-memory)

Comment: No, still doesn't write the folder...

Comment: Note that you do not have rights to create a directory there on Android 11+.

Comment: @CommonsWare So how come WhatsApp mange writing its main folder to internal storage ?

Comment: Perhaps they still have `targetSdkVersion` set to `29`. That will not be an option for you in a couple of months. Also, WhatsApp is owned by Facebook, and Facebook is able to strike deals with device manufacturers that you and I are not. For example, WhatsApp could be pre-installed on the device, and device manufacturers can grant whatever rights that they want to pre-installed apps. Comparing yourself to WhatsApp is not realistic.