# Writing a zip to internal storage -- file doesn't exist after download completion

Tags: android

I used [a tutorial](http://www.hassanpur.com/blog/2011/04/android-development-downloading-a-file-from-the-web/) to download a zip into a subdirectory of my application's internal storage. I wrote the zip to `/data/data/my.package.name/files/mySubDirectory/the.zip`.

But, when I check to see whether the zip exists, it doesn't:

```
    String fileDirectory = this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/mySubDirectory/the.zip";
    File file = new File(fileDirectory);
    if(file.exists()) {
        Log.e(this.class.getName(), "file exists");
    } else {
        Log.e(this.class.getName(), "file doesn't exist");
    }
```

I verified that `fileDirectory` is the same path as the `File outFile` for the `FileOutputStream`.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please can you please tell me the exact path of where your file lies?

Comment: I wrote it to `/data/data/my.package.name/files/mySubDirectory/the.zip`

Comment: @DarrenGreen: Wouldn't accessing /data/data folder require root access?? Perhaps that is the reason for the problem?

Comment: @DarrenGreen: Also, the tutorial you have followed describes how you can download and store files on the SD card.

Comment: I know that the tutorial is for the SD card, but I tweaked it to write to internal storage. I actually figured out my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105919/creating-directory-in-application-package-on-internal-storage), I created a subdirectory using this example:

```
File mydir = context.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myfile"); //Getting a file within the dir.
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir); //Use the stream as usual to write into the file
```

The problem is that I didn't expect the subdirectory to be prepended with "app_", so I was looking for the zip in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  getFilesDir() + "/"  subdirectory + "/" "the.zip"
Without the getabsolutepath(). 
That is what I used could be the issue.

OK maybe you problem is with permissions do you see the file in the DDMS under data/data/package/files    ? Check the permissions for the files

Here is my code

```
         String path = getFilesDir() + "/"
            + subDirName + "/";
            File file = new File(path);
            file.mkdirs();
            setReadable(file);
```

I use the following to make the file readable

```
            @TargetApi(9)
            private void setReadable(File file) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                            try {
                                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                                                    "chmod 777 " + file.getCanonicalPath());
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    } else {
                            file.setReadable(true, false);
                    }
            }
            }
```

Comment: `getFileDir()` returns a `File`. What does that mean when I concat it with other `String`s?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting your file path as below :

> ```
>  String fileDirectory=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "data" + File.separator + "data" + File.separator+ getActivity().getPackageName()+ File.separator +"mySubDirectory"+File.separator+"the.zip";
> ```

Comment: The OP asked about internal storage - your answer is referring to external storage